# rJava parse date string, method not found

Tags: java, r, rjava

In R 3.3.3, using the package rJava (version 0.9-9), running on Linux (RHEL 6.9), I am encountering an error running the following piece of code to create a Java Date from an R string:

```
library(rJava)

rDateString <- "2016-01-01 10:00:00"

.jinit()
df <- .jnew("java/text/SimpleDateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
pp <- .jnew("java/text/ParsePosition", as.integer(0))
d <- .jcall(df, "Ljava/util/Date", "parse", rDateString, pp)
```

This gives the following error:

```
Error in .jcall(df, "Ljava/util/Date", "parse", rDateString, pp) : 
  method parse with signature (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/text/ParsePosition;)Ljava/util/Date not found
```

This confuses me, because this method should be available. Calling `.jmethods` on my SimpleDateFormat object, results in (snip):

```
> .jmethods(df)
 [5] "public java.util.Date java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition)"
```

So, as far as I can tell, I'm complying to the `parse` method signature, yet there is still an error. Can anyone shed some light as to what I am missing here? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing semicolon (`Ljava/util/Date` => `Ljava/util/Date;`):

```
d <- .jcall(df, "Ljava/util/Date;", "parse", rDateString, pp)
d
[1] "Java-Object{Fri Jan 01 10:00:00 CET 2016}"
```

Comment: Brilliant! It's always the little things... Thanks a bunch.